# How to open a new form of bundle from JS Dynamics crm?

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I need to add a custom ADD BUNDLE button to a form that will open a product-bundle form after clicked, my problem is with the functionality, I want to use this:  `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("Entity");`  to open a **product bundle** form, but the only entity I can use is Product, How can I open the product form in Bundle type and not just a product form?

**EDIT: I need to know how to open a product form that its *product structure* is  bundle (3).

[image: a product form in bundle type]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this snippet to do it. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/jj602956(v=crm.8)?redirectedfrom=MSDN#openentityform)

```
var parameters = {};
parameters["productstructure"] = 3;
Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm("product", null, parameters);
```

On a side note, depending on your CRM version - this `Xrm.Utility.openEntityForm` is deprecated. You may have to change to `Xrm.Navigation.openForm` in future. [Learn more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-utility#deprecated-methods)